# RunSpace writing to a logfile

Tags: powershell, logging, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking to use [this Invoke-ScriptAsync](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/) in a `Register-ScheduledJob` to restart servers and log the output.

**Question is, will the Pipe to Out-File be enough for logging? Or is there a more elegant solution to what I'm doing?**

Creating scheduled job:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -once -at $day
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create("D:\Scripts\AsyncReboot.ps1 |
  Out-File -force d:\logs\$comp-Reboot.log")
Register-ScheduledJob -Name $comp -Credential $user -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock $script
```

Now `D:\Scripts\AsyncReboot.ps1` is going to be `Invoke-ScriptAsync` PowerShell Function which includes the script block to perform the reboot plus the standard `$list = Get-Content d:\scripts\Servers.txt`

```
$list = gc D:\Scripts\Servers.txt
Reboot-Async -ScriptBlock $AsyncRebootLogging -InputObject `
  $list -Timeout 120 -MaxThreads 22 | FT -auto
```

Reboot script, this is run as a script block for Invoke-ScriptAsync and the output is not being created.  This worked when I simply had a `"Test reboot of $server"`

```
$AsyncRebootLogging = {
 Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$server)
 $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Try{
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | `
 Select MachineName,TimeGenerated,Message | select -first 1

(Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $server -Path "Win32_Service.Name='HealthService'" -Name `
 PauseService).ReturnValue | Out-Null

Restart-Computer -ComputerName $server -Force

do {"Wait for [$server] to reboot";Start-Sleep -Seconds 4} while (Test-Path "\\$server\C$")

do {"Waiting for [$server]";Start-sleep -Seconds 4} while (-not(Test-Path "\\$server\C$"))

Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '6005'} | `
 Select MachineName,TimeGenerated,Message | select -first 1 | FT -auto

}#End Try.

Catch{
$errMsg = $_.Exception
"Failed with $errMsg"
}
```

Comment: Should work fine, as long as your script blocks are dumping the data you want to log to the pipeline.

Comment: That is what I was unsure of, `D:\Scripts\AsyncReboot.ps1` is just your `Invoke-ScriptAsync` function in a script.  My test run of `"hello world for $server"` was successful, scheduled job and all.

Comment: Well test it and see if it works.  If you don't want to really restart the computers, well, that's what -WhatIf is for.

Comment: It didn't work.  I was able to get output from the runspace sessions with a simple `"Echo test"` but somehow it wasn't the same when the actual script ran.

Comment: What output were you expecting? If there's nothing in your script that outputs to the pipeline then you're not going to get anything back, even if it did run successfully.

Comment: Just added the reboot script, basically the output of `Get-EventLog` to record reboot timestamp before then after.

Comment: I'm guessing my script block isn't outputting data to the pipeline.  I'm looking for any examples but so far have not found any.

Comment: Just an update, I'm still a little stuck on this.  I've been looking around for methods to get a script to output to the pipeline but have not been very successful.  Unless it's as simple as `$output = .\Get-Data.ps1`